# Camel: read tables entrys once

Tags: java, sql, apache-camel

im using camel to translate a h2db into java-objects. It works! But now i dont know how to configurate the camel to read each table entry only once, except it was updated since the last read-in.
I cant read every 2 seconds a db with more than 1 million entrys, so i only want the new entries or the updated.

That's my camel-route:

```
<route id="db-import-route">
        <from uri="timer://queryTimer?period=2s" />
        <setBody>
            <constant>
                SELECT * FROM address
            </constant>
        </setBody>
        <to uri="jdbc:dataSource" />
        <split>
            <simple>${body}</simple>
            <process ref="SqlDecoder" />
            <process ref="Validator" />
        </split>
    </route>
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If your entries have id that is incremented with each new entry, after getting response from jdbc send it to some kind of bean and save the last ID you fetched. Before you send a message to jdbc use the same bean (but different method) to append "where id > saved_id" to your message and then send it to jdbc.

Comment: (That's obviously not the best answer you will get, but "hey, it would work")

Comment: Sry but that's not my problems solution... what happend if someone updated an entry, i want to get it too, not only the newest one.

Comment: But thx for your answer :)

Comment: Oh ok, sorry. You can save timestamp in that bean instead then.

Comment: No Problem, but tanks again. Have to find a diffrent way!